# Android SoundPool is not playing wav format sound

Tags: android, kotlin, soundpool

I'am trying to play .wav format sounds from raw resource file when i click to the button but nothing happens when i click to the button and there is no logcat error.

My MainActivity.kt:

```
 package com.example.exampleofmusicapp

       import android.media.AudioAttributes
       import android.media.AudioManager
       import android.media.SoundPool
       import android.os.Build
       import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
       import android.os.Bundle
       import android.view.View


    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var soundPool: SoundPool

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            var audioAttrs: AudioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .build()

             soundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(2)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttrs)
                .build()
        }

        else{
            soundPool = SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0)
        }

    }

    fun playSound1(view: View) {
        val sound1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1)
        soundPool.play(sound1, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f)
    }

    }
```

Edit: I have tried this in 2 emulator and a real device but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes time to load the sound file into memory so change `val sound1` to `var sound1`, make it global and instantiate it at the end of the `onCreate` method like so:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var soundPool: SoundPool
    var sound1 : Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            var audioAttrs: AudioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .build()

            soundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(2)
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttrs)
                    .build()
        }

        else{
            soundPool = SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0)
        }
        sound1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1)

    }

    fun playSound1(view: View) {
        if(sound1 != 0) {
            soundPool.play(sound1, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f)
        }
    }

}
```

Then you could check `sound1` value and if it's not equal to `0` so it loaded completely. Also you could use `setOnLoadCompleteListener` method of `SoundPool` to check this.